# Implementing this equation in MATLAB with a for loop?

Tags: matlab, loops, for-loop

I am looking to implement the following equation in MATLAB since I have a very large matrix,

[image]

How would I be able to do this? It is not really about the 261 and for the sake of simplicity, we can assume `d = 0.94`, and there is no need to worry about the squared term nor mean term as I will be able to figure that out if I can get the loop concept down. So for instance, I will just try to calculate an average of all the past values in the rows with specific weights attached to them.

To clarify, we can essentially think of `i` as indexing the rows of a matrix and so this consists of an entire column which I provided as an example below. Ignoring the infinity, we can just sum it to period `t`, but the idea is that there is a certain weight placed on all the previous values of the rows where the most recent row has the greatest weight.

I was thinking of using something like this:

```
R = [1; 2; 3; 4; 5; 6; 7; 8; 9; 10];
d = 0.94;
r = zeros(10,1);
for t = 2:10
    r(t,1) = R(t,1);
    for i = 1:10
        W(i,1) = (1-d)*(d.^i)*r(t,1);
    end
end
```

Or even indexing `t = 1:10`.
None of these works. In essence, I want to be able to calculate a mean for which there is greater weight placed to the most recent value. So for example, at row `t=4`, the value I would get would be:

```
(1-0.94)(0.94^3)*(1) + (1-0.94)(0.94^2)(2) +(1-0.94)(0.94)(3).
```

[image]

Comment: I would name your variables in Matlab to reflect what they are in the equation... For example, what is `Matrix`? there is no matrix in your equation. Also, `r` should be a known vector by the looks of things, whereas you are setting it to a 10x10 matrix of zeros. Ignoring the fact that it should be a vector, this will mean your equation will give you zero  no matter what your input values are.

Comment: Your equation has a sum to infinity... which will give you an index of -infinity for `r`... surely that can't be right.

Comment: My bad for the lack of clarification. So the matrix which I have is just one column of data and this can be represented as t being equal to a specific row and it is calculated based off the historical values of the row from 1 up to row t. Where the most recent value prior to row t has a weight that is to the power of 1. On the other hand, row 1 will have a weight that is given by d to the power of t. Hope that is more clear. As for the sum to infinity, it can be interpreted as the sum of all the previous rows prior to some row t in the matrix defined in my example as matrix R.

Comment: Okay... I don't think you need little `r` there. You can just replace it with big `R`. What do you mean by 'historical' values 'where the most recent value [...] has a weight that is to the power of 1'. Is `R` the raw values, or have you already applied some weighting?

Comment: In this case, it would be the raw values. So I am trying to apply the weightings according to **d** to the power of **i** _(d^i) and this would **d^1** for the most recent value. So for the example provided, with t = 4 (4th row), then it would based off the previous values with the highest weight applied to the row before that which is row 3 given by the value 3.

Comment: Right, final question, the mean of r is across all r or only r where i<t?

Comment: Yes, it would be the latter case where i<t. I have attached another example in my original post, that hopefully makes it more clear as my base index should actually begin at the 2nd row, since there are no prior values before row 1. I have corrected this in my original post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right, if I understand you correctly, I think the following should work:

```
R = [1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10];
d = 0.94;

W = zeros(size(R));

% at t = 1, sigma will be 0
for t = 2:length(R)
    meanR = mean(R(1:t-1));
    for i = 1:t-1
        W(t) = W(t) + 261*(1-d)*(d.^(t-i))*(R(i) - meanR)^2;
    end
end
```

Comment: Amazing, thank you very much for your help. I don't know why I couldn't wrap my head around the fact that I needed to include a W(t) in the loop. I have spent so much time trying to find a solution to where I went wrong. Thank you. I would up vote your answer but I am still relatively new to this aspect of stack exchange, but will do so when I have enough points.